# setting the browser's width as a variable in scss

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

How to get the browser's width to use it as a VARIABLE?

I know about the @media. what I need is getting the width and do some calculation to it

I tried using jQuery, it works great if the browser's width is **FIXED**, but when I resize the browse window it doesn't work

here is what I want to do:

html

```
<section id="slider">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide">
        <h1>silde 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      </div>
     <div class="slide">
        <h1>silde 2</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      </div>
    </div> </section>
```

SCSS

```
$browser-width: (BROWSER WIDTH HERE) * .75 ;
#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: $browser-width;
  .slides {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 6000px;
  }
  .slide {
    width: $browser-width;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

What I did as a temporary solution is this:
using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  var width = $(window).width() * .75;   
  var $slider = $('#slider');   
  var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');   
  var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');   

  $slider.css("width", width);   
  $slides.css("width", width);

  /* function to make the slider here */ 
});
```

width = 75% doesn't work nor does width = 75vw

Comment: Is there a reason why `75vw` will not work? `vw` is the viewport width.

Comment: yes it worked, yeah I had a stupid mistake in my sliding function ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I found the problem
vw is the answer, it didn't work because I made this mistake in my sliding function

> 'margin-left' : '-=' + width

what I needed to do was this:

> 'margin-left' : '-=' + width + **"vw"**

never forget the units in your code .. lesson learned

here is my sliding function to those interested:

```
'use strict';


$(document).ready(function(){

  var width = 75;
  var animationSpeed = 1000;
  var pause = 1000;
  var currentSlide = 1;

  var $slider = $('#slider');
  var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
  var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide');

  var interval;


  function startSlider(){
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left' : '-='+width + "vw"}, animationSpeed, function(){
        currentSlide++;
        if (currentSlide === $slides.length){
          currentSlide = 1;
          $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
        }

      });

    }, pause);
  }
function stopSlider(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}

$slider.on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);

startSlider();

});
```

Comment: careful that viewport units cause problems . Read more here https://caniuse.com/#search=viewport